# Remap keys conflicting with plugin

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc

I want to remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>(scroll up) to <kbd>up</kbd>.
However, I also have yankring mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>, and I wish to keep yankring's mapping.
Now if I have this in .vimrc: `map <Up> <C-y>`, pressing <kbd>up</kbd> will trigger yankring.

So is there a way to remap Vim's default key mapping (or map to it's function), whilst having plugin mapped to it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try: `noremap <up> <c-y>`

Regular key maps are recursive, meaning they will invoke your other defined key maps.  `noremap` makes it so that the `{rhs}` uses the default key maps.