# Fixing a mapping action, such that it is not affected by future remappings of its keys

Tags: key-bindings

This is best explained with an example: Suppose I want to remap `G` to go to the end of the line, as I find that convenient. I also want to be able to jump to the end of the file, maybe by pressing `gG`. I might then try the following:

```
nmap gG G
nmap G g_
```

However, that'll not work. Since `G` was remapped to `g_` later on, the action performed by `gG` will not be to go to the end of the file, but the end of the line.

So my question is: Is there a way to "fix" the mapping, so its actions are not affected by later remappings of the keys it uses?

---

*Note: I know the problem above can be solved by other methods, such as using `nmap <silent> gG :$<cr>`. My question is not about solving that specific problem, but more about whether the idea proposed above is possible in vim.*

Comment: `:nnoremap gG G`

Comment: @BLayer Hah, I thought `:nnoremap` only prevented recursion, thanks. Is this question too obvious and should be deleted? If so, feel free to suggest that, if not, feel free to leave your comment as an answer.

Comment: It's almost certainly a duplicate. There are so many answers containing "nnoremap", though, that it could be hard to find a proper dupe match. I like the title of your question, though, since it's nice and general (and likely to be hit by searches) so I'm hoping we can find one ... deleting is not ideal.

Comment: Best one I've found so far: [Remap keys conflicting with plugin](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7472)  It's not ideal that it mentions "plugin" in the title though, obviously. And the answer is pretty brief. {sigh} Hoping someone else just knows a good one.